# Regexp: find out if value that repeats several times

Tags: regex

I have strings:

```
TH 8H 5C QS TC
9S 4S JS KS JS
```

I want the second one to be picked up by `reqexp`. Help me please to contract the necessary expression. 
What I tried so far is: `S{5}` but of course it look up sequentially.

- Could I avoid determining which character I am looking for. I need 5 repetition of any. Could it be like .{5} ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "second one"? It's not clear to me.

Comment: I want `9S 4S JS KS JS` to be picked up by `regexp` because it has 5 occurrences of 'S'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have standalone strings, use

```
^\wS(?: \wS){4}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lF5cQ5/1)

If these strings appear inside a larger text, replace the `^` and `$` anchors with word boundaries `\b`:

```
\b\wS(?: \wS){4}\b
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/lF5cQ5/2)

Note that `\w` matches any alphanumeric or underscore character. If there can be any non-whitespace character, use `\S` instead:

```
\b\SS(?: \SS){4}\b
```

One [more demo](https://regex101.com/r/lF5cQ5/3)

`\SS` will match a non-whitespace followed with an `S` and `(?: \SS){4}` will match 4 same sequences (thus, there will be 5 2-character sequences with `S` at the end of each).

Comment: Define what kind of character can be before `S`. If any alphanumeric/underscore - then `\w`. If any non-whitespace - `\S`. If an ASCII letter - `[A-Za-z]`. If uppercase only: `[A-Z]`.

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor. Could it be universal pattern for one string to look up 'S' and for another 'A' occurrences?

Comment: If you mean to match `9S 4S JS KS JA` as well, you can use `\b\S[AS](?: \S[AS]){4}\b`. If you plan to match both `9S 4S JS KS JS` and `9S 4A JA KA JA`, use `\b\S([AS])(?: \S\1){4}\b`.

Comment: I finished writing the above comment. Use the capture group with a character class `([AS])` and then a back reference `\1` if you need all 5 chunks to have the same character at the end.