# Regex: Poker hand parser, N of a kind

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a `regex` to parse a poker hand:
e.g:

```
4C 4H 6H 4D AH
4H 6H 4D 4C AH
4C 6H 4D AH 4H
```

I would like to have universal regexp to parse every single row below and return true if it contains three times `4`. What I have so far derived from my previous question about [sequence of repetition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35629292/regexp-find-out-if-value-that-repeats-several-times) and doesn't consider fact that cards can be shuffled.

What I tried so far is: 
 `4\w((?: \w{2})?(?: 4\w)){2}` - it covers several cases but not all of them. Please, help me to fix this expression.

---

**Edited:**

```
def check_card_series(hand, range):
    #  4\w((?: \w{2})?(?: 4\w)){2}
    regexp = "%s\w((?: \w{2})?(?: %s\w)){%d}"
    result = False
    for card in cards:
        result = re.search(regexp % (card, card, range - 1), str(hand))
        if result:
            return result
    return result
```

I use `regexp` inside `Python` method. Could you please help me to separate things and show me a better heuristic of doing this.

Comment: Can you not just count the number of matches? Seems overly complicated to do it all with regex.

Comment: There are great C# libraries for poker math, if you are real about poker, and do not do the task only as an exercise, there is no why to reinvent the wheel (and have it slower). See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12279/Fast-Texas-Holdem-Hand-Evaluation-and-Analysis for example.

Comment: @Novocaine, I edited question, could you take a look once more

Comment: @Wapac, thanks but it's just an exercise

Comment: Narrow `4C 4H 6H 4D AH` to `4 4 6 4 A` then count the number of occurrences of each *card*. Use an hammer if you have nails, not if you have screws...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of programming logic and regular expressions:

```
import re

decks = ['4C 4H 6H 4D AH','4H 6H 4D 4C AH','4C 6H 4D AH 4H', '4C 4H 4D AH 4H']

rx = re.compile(r'4[A-Z]')
for deck in decks:
    matches = len(rx.findall(deck))
    if matches == 4:
        print deck
        # output: 4C 4H 4D AH 4H
```

Counts the numbers of found matches and prints out the actual deck if `4+letter` can be found exactly four times.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to write regexp so it can explain itself:

```
four = r'4\w '
not_four = r'[^4]\w '
not_four_seq = r'(%s)*' % not_four
res = r'^%s(%s%s){3}$' % (not_four_seq, four, not_four_seq)
if re.match(res, '7C 4H 4H 5D 4H' + ' '):
    print 'OK'
```

Answer (score 0):

It just prints the hand. Use this approch

```
import re

test_str = "4C 4H 6H 4D AH\n4H 6H 4D 4C AH\n4C 6H 4D AH 4H\n6H 4D 6H 6H 6H"    
test_split = test_str.split("\n")

def check_hand(hand):
    p = re.compile(ur'(4\w).*(4\w).*(4\w)')
    result = re.match(p, hand)
    if result:
        return True

for hand in test_split:
    if check_hand(hand):
        print(hand)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a general answer to search for a few simple 'hands' try:

```
import re


hands = ['4C 4H 6H 4D AH','4H 6H 4D 4C AH','4C 6H 4D AH 4H','10C 10H JD AH 4H']
denom_list = ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K','A']

for hand in hands:
    for denom in denom_list:
        regex = '({0}[HCDS])'.format(denom)
        match = re.findall(regex,hand)
        if len(match)==4:
            result = "Four of a kind: (4x{0})".format(denom)
        elif len(match)==3:
            result = "Three of a kind: (3x{0})".format(denom)
        elif len(match)==2:
            result = "Pair: (2x{0})".format(denom)
        elif len(match)==2:
            result = "High Card: (1x{0})".format(denom)
    print(hand,' -> ',result)
```